# String.match RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, error-handling

Can this line of code

```
someString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
```

cause this issue: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
by any means?

this is being called in a method, which is inside a loop to process n no. of images

```
function imageUpload(images) {
  for (index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
    base64Data = images[index];
    imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(base64Data);
  }
}

function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
  matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
  response = {};
  if (matches.length !== 3) {
    return new Error('Invalid input string');
  }

  response.type = matches[1];
  response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');
  return response;
}
```

Could this be global vars?

**Note**: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. We just caught this over sentry for production environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a sample test string?

Comment: @tadman its simply base64 data converted from image like this one here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6k4huwf9h4odeg/image_string.txt?dl=0

Comment: Right, but do you have one that causes the "Maximum call stack size" error.

Comment: @tadman no, as I said I was not able to reproduce this one. it was caught over sentry on production.

Comment: I'd try encoding a really large file and see what happens. 1GB should do it.

Comment: you mean 1 GB  of image size data should be used as input to produce this?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, if you can't reproduce it you can't understand it. I'd guess that an excessively large string *might* cause the problem. Maybe you can verify.

Answer (score 3):

The question is 2 years old, but I had the same problem, this was the first google result and found a solution.

Yes, the regex can throw the mentioned error. I had the same regex just with more capturing groups (`/^data:([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z-+0-9/]+);base64,(.+)$/`).

While the regex works for smaller images or files, it does not work for bigger files. In my case, an .jpeg-Image with the dimensions 4624x3468 and the size of 3,67mb was too large.

### Solution:

You can use basic string operations for everything you need:

```js
        const base64SearchText = ';base64,';
        const indexBase64SearchText = src.indexOf(base64SearchText);
        const indexSlash = src.indexOf('/');

        // src is not a base64 URL
        if (indexBase64SearchText === -1 || indexSlash === -1 || !src.startsWith('data:')) {
            return src;
        }
        
        // fileType is image, video, ect (first part of mime-type)
        const fileType = src.substring('data:'.length, indexSlash);
        // fileEnding is second part of mime-type
        const fileEnding = src.substring(indexSlash + 1, indexBase64SearchText);
        // data is the raw base64-string. This is most likely what you want to use
        const data = src.substring(indexBase64SearchText + base64SearchText.length);

       // do with fileType, fileEnding and data what you want
```

Keep in mind that there are better options than to send images/files in base64 to the backend, like FormData or Blobs/Bytes per sockets. But if you want to use base64, the above works.